# Get the Highest/Maximum Grouped By Value in a report/dashboard

Tags: reporting, dashboard, lightning-experience, report-chart

I have a dashboard component based on a report in which Opportunities are Grouped By CreatedDate with sum of revenue for every day.

The output is something like below. (Each color represents each day and the revenue values).

[image]

What I want is ONLY the highest/greatest amount among these values (3.5k) to be displayed.  OR I want to know on which Date is the highest amount and display only that date.  How can I get this done in a report/dashboard?

I don't mind changing the funnel to a metric or any other dashboard type and also willing to use 2 different reports/dashboard components etc.

Note:  This is in Lightning Experience.

Answer (score 2):

> EDIT: Note that this answer is only valid for non-lightning dashboards. The question turned out to be on a Lightning Experience dashboard. Nevertheless I'm leaving the answer here so it might help other people.

In the dashboard Component Editor (click on the little wrench on the top-right of the dashboard component), in the Formatting tab, you can set 'Maximum Values Displayed'. Set that to 1 and the 'Sort Rows By' to 'Value Descending'. That should get you what you want.

Example screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Forgot to mention, this is in Lightning Experience!

Comment: So these options aren't available in Lightning Experience.  And to do this in classic, I have to completely re-do my whole dashboard in Classic, which  is not a good option for me, right now.

Comment: sorry, it's indeed part of the limitations mentioned here: https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=lex_gaps_limitations_analytics.htm